# OpenPDF not showing SetRowspan

Tags: java, itext, openpdf

Trying to move from iText 5.x.x to OpenPDF version.  I added the latest openpdf to my maven.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
     <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
     <version>1.3.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Import the code into my java.

```
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
```

But when I enter the SetRowspan it says it's not found.  Doesn't even show in the helper dropdown.

[image: missing in the dropdown]

The documentation says it's there. SetColumnspan works fine.  No idea what I'm missing.  Thoughts/suggestions?

Comment: I had a quick look, `PdfPCell.setRowspan` has been added to iText in version 2.1.6 and as such has been in OpenPDF ever since it was forked from iText. Also I clearly see it in the current OpenPDF sources. Thus, could it be that you additionally have a pre-2.1.6 version of iText in your class path? That would explain why you find a `PdfPCell` class without a `setRowspan` method.

Comment: Looks like I also have this in maven 
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>

Comment: You'll have to decide which `com.lowagie.*` iText/OpenPDF version you want to use.